# r plotly - how to prevent hover name being truncated

Tags: r, hover, plotly, r-plotly

The hover name that appears outside the hover box on my plotly plot is getting cutoff because of the long names. I have found solutions for [plotly.js](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/460) and [plotly.py](https://community.plot.ly/t/re-size-hover-info-box/955) but not R. I have been able to remove that name from the hover or move it into the box with the value, but need a solution that keeps it in place while allowing the entire name to be visible.

```
# sample data
Value <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
Time <- c(1:100)
Site <- "Really long name for Site 1"
datTemp <- data.frame(Time, Value, Site)

Value <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
Time <- c(1:100)
Site <- "Really long name for Site 2"
datTemp2 <- data.frame(Time, Value, Site)

Value <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
Time <- c(1:100)
Site <- "Really long name for Site 3"
datTemp3 <- data.frame(Time, Value, Site)    

figTemp<-datTemp%>%
    plot_ly(x = ~Time, y = ~Value, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", line = list(width = 0.75), name = ~Site[1])%>%
    layout(xaxis = list(title = "Date"), yaxis = list(title = "Temperature (C)"), legend = list(x = 0, y = 1.05, orientation = "h"))

figTemp<-figTemp%>%
    add_trace(data = datTemp2, y = ~Value, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", name = ~Site[1])%>%
    add_trace(data = datTemp3, y = ~Value, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", name = ~Site[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `hovertemplate = paste('(%{x}, %{y})')` to your call to `plot_ly`. Worked. Try this:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
# sample data
Value <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
Time <- c(1:100)
Site <- "Really long name for Site 1"
datTemp <- data.frame(Time, Value, Site)

Value <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
Time <- c(1:100)
Site <- "Really long name for Site 2"
datTemp2 <- data.frame(Time, Value, Site)

Value <- rnorm(100, mean = 5)
Time <- c(1:100)
Site <- "Really long name for Site 3"
datTemp3 <- data.frame(Time, Value, Site)    

figTemp<-datTemp%>%
  plot_ly(x = ~Time, y = ~Value, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", line = list(width = 0.75), name = ~Site[1],
          hovertemplate = paste('(%{x}, %{y})')) %>%
  layout(xaxis = list(title = "Date"), yaxis = list(title = "Temperature (C)"), legend = list(x = 0, y = 1.05, orientation = "h"))

figTemp<-figTemp%>%
  add_trace(data = datTemp2, y = ~Value, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", name = ~Site[1]) %>%
  add_trace(data = datTemp3, y = ~Value, type = "scatter", mode = "lines", name = ~Site[1])

figTemp
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Huh, so just by specifying _something_ about the template, it corrects itself. Odd but works, thanks!

Comment: That was exactly my thought when I figured out that it works. (;